# is considered / is considered to be / is considered as

Tags: phrase-meaning

As I understand it, all the sentences may be used. But I don't understand when there is need to add "to be" after "is considered". Could you explain the nuances of these examples, please? For me, the first sentence & the third one are absolutely the same.
(From [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=considered%20to%20be%20the%20language%2Cconsidered%20as%20the%20language%2C%20considered%20the%20language&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=17&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20to%20be%20the%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20as%20the%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20the%20language%3B%2Cc0) I see that the first one is more common.)

> French **is considered** the language of love.
>
> French **is considered to be** the language of love.
>
> French **is considered as** the language of love.

P.S. From my online course I have received a sentence: French is considered to be **a language of love**. I think it's a mistake because there is said about the certain category of language.

Comment: I think both "French is a language..." and "French is the language..." are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, the phrase **to be** is often elided. The sentence is perfectly correct either way.

However, if you were talking about a historical figure, you would usually omit **to be** as it implies that the person is still alive.

I say usually because historical figures are sometimes reanimated, as in: **Shakespeare is considered to be the world's greatest playwright.** One comes across this construction in the place of the more correct **to have been** because the comparison includes playwrights both living and dead.

**Is considered as** is an alternative way of saying the same thing.

I don't see any problem with your example about French as a language of love, although it would more usually be phrased as **the** language of love.